# Write shorter For Loop for Array

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following For Loop to copy and paste several ranges from one sheet to another.  I used an array. The procedure works fine, but I was looking for a shorter way to do the same.

```
Dim copyRange(1 To 3) As String
Dim pasteRange(1 To 3) As String
Dim refRange(1 To 3) As String
Dim i As Long

copyRange(1) = "A5"
copyRange(2) = "G5"
copyRange(3) = "H5"

refRange(1) = "A"
refRange(2) = "G"
refRange(3) = "H"

pasteRange(1) = "BE3"
pasteRange(2) = "CA2"
pasteRange(3) = "CD2"

For i = 1 To 3

         refApplicantFlow.Range(copyRange(i), refApplicantFlow.Range(refRange(i) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy _
            calcCalculations.Range(pasteRange(i))

Next i
```

Comment: your loop is 1 line of code, how many lines should be in shorter code?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the `Range(target(i)).Value = Range(source(i)).Value` syntax? Where `target` and `source` are arrays of strings that identify the range(s) to copy values to and from?

Comment: There are only 3 ranges being copied, and most of the lines are just setup for the loop. Do you need to use a loop instead of just 3 lines doing the copying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would strongly recommend, to store the references to the cells as hard coded strings in your macro. The moment your workbook's structure is slightly adjusted, your macros will fail/copy the wrong things!

Instead, use named ranges. I.e. click on `A5` and assign the name `Source_1` or so to it. `G5` will become `Source_2`, `H5` `Source_1`, `G5` `Target_1`, etc.

The use this code:

```
lngRows = Rows.Count
For i = 1 To 3
   Range("Target_"&i).Resize(lngRows).Value = Range("Source_"&i).Resize(lngRows).Value
Next
```

This way, your macro will still work, even if the workbook structure changes! And your line of code became shorter! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your macro is pretty efficient if the intent was to include a loop and arrays. The same thing could be accomplished in 3 lines:

```
refApplicantFlow.Range("A5", refApplicantFlow.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy _
calcCalculations.Range("BE3")
refApplicantFlow.Range("G5", refApplicantFlow.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy _
calcCalculations.Range("CA2")
refApplicantFlow.Range("H5", refApplicantFlow.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy _
calcCalculations.Range("CD2")
```